# AWS Terraform - push message to SQS every X minutes using CloudWatch shedule

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

What resources do I need to set up to create a schedule which will push message to a SQS queue with body specified within terraform?

I found this https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_rule
but I can't see a field which would let me input body of message.

How I imagine this:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_something" "sheduled_event" {
  sqs_arn          = 
  event_body       =
  cron_expression  = 
}
```

It would push `event_body` to `sqs_arn` queue every `cron_expression`.

Is it achievable in terraform?

Comment: You already answered your own question. You have to use `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule`.

Comment: @Marcin where do I specify body of message though? I can't see any example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to associate an event rule with an [event target](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_event_target). However, the SQS target doesn't allow you to specify body content; it will always receive the body of the event.

I think a better approach (although more complex) is to introduce a Lambda: the EventBridge rule triggers the Lambda, which writes a message to the queue.